# is the dupe finder working?

Tags: duplicate-contacts

I create a general rule to search my database of 29000 contacts for matching emails - I know there are a few at least, and it says there are none. Also I give it a weight and match that in the threshold but after saving the rule and going back to it, the weight has reset to 0. the same happens with the length setting.

Any clues?

Myles
Civi 4.6.10 on drupal

Comment: always useful to go and compare the outcomes on the demo sites

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the rule you are using is for the type of contacts in your db, generally Individual. Then get the rule saved with a weight on the email field >= threshold, with the latter being > 0. Once you have verified this is configured properly by clicking to edit again, then try using the rule.